# missing changes in commits in git

Tags: git, git-flow

I have a team of a few people working on the same git repository, using the git flow method (master, develop, hotfixes, features, releases), and a remote bare repository.

We had a hotfix with a few commits that was merged successfully into master and all was good.
Now, a week later, and a lot of changes later, after continuing to work on develop, we had a release branch that was not merged into master as well.

We noticed that some files in the system got reverted back to the state they were **before the hotfix**. These files were only touched lately in the hotfix mentioned, and no further changes were made on them in the develop branch.

The weird part is that I can't find a merge in the git log history that shows a conflict on any of these files, which can indicate that a team member got a conflict and didn't resolve it correctly.

All I can see are the commits from the hotfix which added the desired changes, but I can't find a later commit that reverts those changes.

I tried using `git whatchanged -p -r -m -- myfile` and again, all I see are the commits from the hotfix.

How can I find out what happened to those files? Could it be a corruption in my repository?

Comment: How are you looking for diffs that "shows a conflict"? By default, if a file matches one or other parent in a diff, `git log` will assume it's not interesting and not show it in the patch output.

Comment: AFAIK if there are conflicts in a merge, then the modified files will show up in the files list of the merge commit.
So I'm expecting to see my file in a git log/whatchanged.

Comment: I think you need to change your expectations. There might have been a conflict but if it was resolved to take the file as it was in one parent then log won't show a patch. If that parent happened to be the first parent then it won't show even if you are showing patches with `-m`. I'm unclear as to which branch you believe has lost the "hotfixes" and which way around you believe that a merge may have "merged out" these changes so I'm not quite sure if this is the situation is likely to match what you've experienced.

Comment: When I run git whatchanged on the file, I see the history of changes applied to it. I see the original commit where the new code was added, but there's no follow up commit where those lines are removed, yet the file in HEAD doesn't contain those new lines. How does that make sense? I find it hard to believe that I can't find out where/when the decision was made to revert the file.

Comment: I'm not saying you cannot find the commit that changed those files, I just don't think that your invocation of `log` isn't _necessarily_ the correct way to go about it. Just because I'm not quite sure what is going on, I would suggest "brute forcing" it with something like: `for c in $(git rev-list --full-history <branch>); do echo $c $(git rev-parse $c:<file>); done` and look for where the id of the file changes and then examine the suspect commit in detail with something like `git diff <commit>^ <commit>` and `git diff <commit>^2 <commit>`.

Comment: This is really good stuff, thanks. But using this script is confusing, because the output treats my branch as if it's flat, when in fact my branch has many merges in it from other branches, so finding two consecutive lines with a different hash doesn't reflect a change between those two commits.

I'm still working on this, along with the git bisect tool that I was just introduced to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git has a build in mechanism for that.

bisect:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html

run this build in tool and you will be able to track the problematic commit where your changes disappeared.

Read more here to understand how to use it and how it work.
http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/07/git-tip-of-week-git-bisect.html

Comment: This is a really awesome tool, thanks! But I'm still trying to find the right way to work with it to find my problem. I currently don't understand the following behavior: I'm running bisect with HEAD as a bad commit and another commit from a week ago as a good commit, and I keep marking commits as bad, trying to find a state where my code changes exist, but I see that bisect steps out of the time frame and goes back to commits from 2 weeks ago, which of course do not contain my code changes.

Comment: I finally managed to use it correctly by checking out the release branch instead of master, where bisect was able to pinpoint the problematic commit.